# How do I integrate $\frac1{(x-1)^3}$ and prove it equals $-\frac1{2(x-1)^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

In calculus, how do I proof the integral of  $\dfrac{1}{(x-1)^3}$  is $-\dfrac{1}{2(x-1)^2}$.

I know how I can derive $\dfrac{1}{2(x-1)^2}$ to  $-\dfrac{1}{(x-1)^3}$, but I can't seem to do integrate the other way.

Thank you

Comment: Can you integrate $u^{-3}$?

Comment: Differentiate one, there can be only one answers. Integration is the inverse to differentiation so ...

Comment: yaix, added the minus. my mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{(x-1)^3}=(x-1)^{-3}=1\cdot (x-1)^{-3}=\underbrace{x'\cdot(x-1)^{-3}=\left[\frac{(x-1)^{-2}}{-2}\right]'}_{\displaystyle \int u'(x)(u(x))^k\,dx=\frac{(u(x))^{k+1}}{k+1}\text{, for any }k\neq -1}$$